# selecting tableView cell on iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have an `UITableView` and when I select a cell I wanna put a checkmark on the right of the cell....which is pretty easy.

To this end I did the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableViewMieux deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        UIImageView *checkBox = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-pressed.png"]] autorelease];
        checkBox.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
        selectedCell.accessoryView = checkBox;  
        selectedCell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }    
    else  if (selectedCell.accessoryType==UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)     
        {
            UIImageView *checkBox = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"]] autorelease];
            checkBox.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
            selectedCell.accessoryView = checkBox;
            selectedCell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }   
    [tableViewMieux  reloadData];
}
```

Everything works great except the fact that when I select the first cell this gets checkmarked and the fifth cell gets checkmarked automatically too.
And so on...if I select the second cell this gets checkmarked ...and another cell from the bottom of the tableView gets marked too.

So, each time I select and mark a cell and extra cell gets marked.

```
Question:Why?What is the right way to do it?
```

EDIT:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewMieux dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellRecherchePartenaires"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"CellRecherchePartenaires"] autorelease];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        cell.backgroundView.opaque = NO;

        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.opaque = NO;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];

        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.opaque = NO;
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

        cell.accessoryView=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    }

    // Set up the cell...
    [[cell textLabel] setText: [tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: change the name of your cell,

Comment: do it something like indexpath.section, indexpath.row, instead of  cell identifier

Comment: @george please show me your code for `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` once you do, I'll edit my answer below to show you what mrd meant..

Comment: I edited my question with the code.Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.backgroundView.opaque = NO;

    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.opaque = NO;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];

    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.opaque = NO;
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

    cell.accessoryView=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

}

// Set up the cell...
[[cell textLabel] setText: [tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ;

return cell;
```

}

Simply try this ...

Answer (score 2):

add the following lines

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


if([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
  {
      temp = [myarray objectAtInadex:indexpath.row];// change the line according to ur code

   //temp is any object.. //array is nsmutable array(global)
   [array removeObject:temp];

   [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]] autorelease];
   [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
   return;
  }
  else
  {
//temp is any objecct....//arry is nsmutable array(global)
   [array addObject:temp];   
   [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"]] autorelease];
   [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];


  }
 }
```

}

In cell for row index path

```
 temp = [myarray objectAtInadex:indexpath.row];// change the line according to ur code
    if ([array containsObject:temp]) {
      cell.accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"]] autorelease];

      [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
     }
     else 
     {
      cell.accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]] autorelease];
      [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
     }
```

In number of Rows In section

```
[array removeAllObjects];
```

Try, it will work. sure

Comment: please check the elements in array, when u are debugging..and any probs,post it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. It is most probably because you are reusing the cells (with the cell identifier. which is what you should be doing). To solve this, in the delegate

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

do the following:

```
static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

// Get reusable cell if possible
UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                   reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Remove checkmark if cell is not the one that should be checked
int idx = [workingDatasource indexOfObject:currentSupposedToBeChecked];
if (idx != indexPath.row) 
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
else
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

**EDIT:** more explanation:

So, **workingDatasource** is the array which contains the datasource of the UITableView, and **currentSupposedToBeChecked** is an instance variable containing the actual data (which must be one of the data in the datasource) that should be checked.

So on each touch (i.e. in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate) you should save the selected object by doing

```
self.currentSupposedToBeChecked = [workingDatasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: whi is workingDatasource, please do tell...cause I can't figure out!?

Answer (score 0):

To the question why that is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This method that you are calling here: `UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` returns a Cell, but apple designed it that way that cells aren't created from scratch every time but rather cells are being reused, so your 5th and 20th cell in a tableview might be the "same one" because when you scroll down, the cell gets released once it's out of vision and the ones you scroll to are being created as you scroll, that way less memory is being used for a tableview.

As to how to solve this issue, I'm not sure but you have to ... apparently look at mrd3650's solution which he posted as I'm typing :)

Answer (score 0):

I have added another answer for clarity's sake...

I have made comments `//--Added--->` where i have edited.

If there are something which is not clear leave a comment.

Note that `self.currentlySelected` must be declared as a `NSString` property (can be private)

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableViewMieux deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        UIImageView *checkBox = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-pressed.png"]] autorelease];
        checkBox.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
        selectedCell.accessoryView = checkBox;  
        selectedCell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }    
    else  if (selectedCell.accessoryType==UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)     
        {
            UIImageView *checkBox = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"]] autorelease];
            checkBox.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
            selectedCell.accessoryView = checkBox;
            selectedCell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }   

//-----ADDED---->>

int idx = [tableArray indexOfObject:self.currentlySelected];
if (idx != indexPath.row) 
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
else
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

//-----ADDED----<<

    [tableViewMieux  reloadData];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewMieux dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellRecherchePartenaires"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"CellRecherchePartenaires"] autorelease];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        cell.backgroundView.opaque = NO;

        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.opaque = NO;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];

        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.opaque = NO;
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

        cell.accessoryView=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    }

    // Set up the cell...
    [[cell textLabel] setText: [tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ;

//----ADDED--->>
// Save currently selected text - NOTE this must be a property
self.currentlySelected = [tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//----ADDED---<<

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @george, do you want your checkmarks to stay selected? if so, I have to make a small modification to the code I posted above.